# Codeigniter Pagination is not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My Controller:-**

```
public function index($id,$page=0) {

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/categorypage/index/".$id."/";
    $total_row = $this->Categorymodel->record_count($id);
    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
    $config["per_page"] = 20;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = $total_row;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3) ;

    $data["results"] = $this->Categorymodel->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page,$id);
    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

    $this->load->view('frontend/template/other_head');
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/category_nav');
    $this->load->view('frontend/category_content',$data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/footer');
}
```

**My Model**

```
class Categorymodel extends CI_Model {

    // Count all record of table "contact_info" in database.
    public function record_count($catid) {

        //$this->db->where('cat_id',$catid);
         $query = $this->db->get("tbl_product");
        return $query->num_rows();

    }

    // Fetch data according to per_page limit.
    public function fetch_data($limit,$page, $pageid) {

        $this->db->limit(12,$limit);
        $this->db->where('cat_id', $pageid);
        $query = $this->db->get("tbl_product");
        //echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't get the "Offset" value, and The Pagination Url is not fetching other value. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: First off you do not need to include the index function `base_url() . "index.php/categorypage/index/".$id."/";` change to `base_url() . "index.php/categorypage/".$id."/";` second you may need to set your base url and set up some routes http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: also you could save some lines and don't put $row to new array just: `return $query->result_array();`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have bug here:

```
$this->db->limit(12,$limit);
```

Should be limit($limit, $page)